# How to get jazzy style docs on cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire, jazzy

I would like to ask how come the docsets of [Alamofire](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/3.3.1/) and [Restofire](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Restofire/0.8.0/) different.

Is there any way i can render the documentation of Restofire to be like Alamofire.

When i see below Alamofire documentation, they are generated using jazzy. How to tell cocoa pods to generate comments using jazzy.?

Answer (score 0):

When i updated my cocoapods gem to 1.0.0-beta.8, cocoadocs are not generated using jazzy and so it is also updated on website.